# com object and interfaces

Tags: c++, com, interface

What is an interface connected to a com object?

Comment: Do you want documentation links? Are you after something specific?

Comment: Ninja OP ! One question per minute.

Comment: Ist becuase I am going over new code right now and I have a lot of questions.

Comment: What does "connected" mean here? Do you have any example to illustrate that?

Comment: I am not sure myself.  Someone wrote that a com object has a few interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each object implements one or more COM interfaces.

A COM interface is a fixed description of what an object can do - in terms of C++ that's a class without member variables and with pure virtual member functions only. A COM class is an implementation of one or more interfaces - in terms of C++ it's a class (usually with member variables) with actually implemented member functions.

When you say that a COM class "has" some COM interfaces it means that it implements them and can retrieve a pointer to each of those interfaces - that's very similar to an upcast in terms of C++, but is done with `IUnknown::QueryInterface()` function of the actual COM class.

Answer (score 1):

```
"COM Interfaces
The separation between service user and implementation is done by indirect function 
calls. A COM interface is nothing more than a named table of function pointers 
(methods), ..."
```

See more information at [The COM Programmer's Cookbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809982.aspx)